# Reverse of aggregate() by inserting new rows for observations not yet present

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have data that has the following form:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(x = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  values = c(10, 20, 5))
```

```
   x values
1: A     10
2: B     20
3: C      5
```

and a corresponding code list for matching in the following form

```
cl <- data.table(old = c("A", "B", "C", "C"),
                 new = c("A1", "B1", "C1", "C2"))
```

Now I would like to convert the category of `x` from old to new, i.e. A becomes A1, B becomes B1, and C becomes two new observations C1 and C2 so that the data looks like that:

```
    x values
1: A1     10
2: B1     20
3: C1      5
4: C2      5
```

So what I want to do is sort of the opposite of aggregation. I know that for base R there is aggregate(), is there something similar for what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I realized a simple merge is all I need:

```
result <- merge(dat, cl, by.x = "x", by.y = "old", allow.cartesian = TRUE)
```

```
   x values new
1: A     10  A1
2: B     20  B1
3: C      5  C1
4: C      5  C2
```